# Проблема с кодировкой

Tags: кодировка

Здравствуйте. Такая вот ситуация: у меня весь сайт находится в кодировке UTF-8. А сервер, который находиться у меня на компьютере, читает только UTF-8 BOOM, а по 300 раз менять кодировку, то для провайдера, то для себя не имею желания. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что за сервер? ПО, ОС?

Comment: Напишите скрипт, который будет менять кодировку автоматически. В интернете есть готовые решения на PHP. Google Вам в помощь.

Answer (score 4):

Перенастройте свой сервер на работу с UTF-8 без BOM, тогда проблема себя исчерпает.